# Find the N-th smallest round integer

Tags: c++, algorithm, math

An integer is round if it is greater than 0 and the sum of its digits in decimal representation is a multiple of 10.Find the N-th smallest round integer.

1≤N≤10^18

I have tried the naive approach, but the solution is not working fine for large constraint.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h> 
 using namespace std; 

 int sumOfDigits(int n) 
 { 
  int sum = 0; 
  while (n > 0) { 
    sum += n % 10; 
    n /= 10; 
   } 

    return sum; 
 } 

 int findNum(int n) 
 { 
   int c=0, num=0;

    while (c != n) { 
    num++; 
    int sum = sumOfDigits(num); 
    if (sum % 10 == 0) 
        c++; 
 } 

  return num; 
 } 

 int main() 
{ 
 int t, n;
 cin>>t;
 while(t--){
    cin>>n;
    cout<<findNum(n)<<endl;
 }
 }
```

Is there any good approach to solve this problem. Please don't paste the whole solution I just want the approach to solve this.

I have tried another approach also..but the solution is not working fine.

```
  public static long findNth(int n) 
  { 
    long nthElement = 19 + (n - 1) * 9; 
    int outliersCount = (int)Math.log10(nthElement) - 1; 

    nthElement += 9 * outliersCount; 
    return nthElement; 
  }
```

There will series form: 19, 28, 37, 46, 55, 64.....but remember to remove 100, 1000...so on.

Considering this I have tried the solution above but it's not working.

I'm using one of the approaches answered. But this is not working fine too..

```
int sumOfDigits(int n) 
{ 
int sum = 0; 
while (n > 0) { 
    sum += n % 10; 
    n /= 10; 
} 
if(sum%10==0) return 0;
else if(sum<10) return 10-sum;
return 10-sum%10;
} 

long long findNum(int n) 
{ 
return n*10+sumOfDigits(n);
}
```

Comment: I assume on your platform an `int` is sufficiently large to hold 1,000,000,000,000,000,000.

Comment: i tried with long long also, but this naive approach is taking too much time

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56522649/algorithm-for-computing-round-integers

Comment: When manipulating digits of a number (or reading them), treat the number as a string.  You can fetch a digit with: `int digit = number_as_text[i] - '0';`.  This may be more efficient than using division or remainder to extract the digits.

Comment: The duplicate algorithm-for-computing-round-integers has a -6 and it's on hold @Damien

Comment: @dustbuster I know. At least I wanted to let people look at the answer there. It is clear that there is a risk that this duplicate question will be deleted. I don't know which position to adopt in such a situation. I noticed that the question here was not put on hold, despite the duplicate

Comment: @Damien Yes it's surely worth looking at. I don't think this question is likely to get voted down on dupe status though. I did not vote to remove this question, and that's how I wound up here. I suggest the author make this a more viable question than the other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One important hint: If the first `n-1` digits of an `n`-digit integer are fixed, there exists exactly one digit that can be used as the last digit to satisfy the condition. In other words, there is exactly one integer that satisfies the required condition in every 10 integers (starting from 10). Based on this there is a very simple solution to the problem that generates the answer directly rather than enumerating integers one by one and verifying the condition.

Comment: I have tried this approach also. Above is the code snippet. But this solution is also not correct.

Comment: You need to create some test cases and run your code on them to see which cases your code fails.

Comment: You have integer overflows in multiple places.

Comment: Can you please suggest some case where it is failed. I have tried a lot, but i'm not getting it.  @BalázsKovacsics

Comment: In your code, `n` has a type of `int`, but it should be able to hold a number as high as 10^18, which only fits in a 64-bit integer (`long` or `long long`, depending on the platform)

Comment: The solution was correct, only the problem is of range. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try to find some pattern in the numbers that fulfil this condition, and you can find a more efficient solution than just iterating over every number.

Comment: This should be a comment.

Comment: i have tried this also, but the solution is not working fine.

Comment: @vivek_23 as the request was specifically not to post a complete solution, I don't think a more detailed answer is possible.

Comment: @vivek_23 Nope, this is a valid answer. Giving the details of such a patterns is giving too much help and anything less is no answer.

Comment: @NitinSinghal Then obviously, you made some error(s). Try to avoid those and you will succeed!

Comment: @BalázsKovacsics OP does ask `Please don't paste the whole solution I just want the approach to solve this.`. So you could show the pattern if you know.

Comment: @Walter OP does ask for a pattern/approach but not the code.

Comment: just give me some pattern hint at least, I already know this there's some pattern.

Comment: The second solution you posted only works until 190, because 199 doesn't satisfy the condition.

Comment: You have to consider separately cases where the sum of digits is 10, 20, 30, etc.
They are in different series.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the numbers satisfying this criterion

19, 28 ... 91, 109, 118 ... 190, 208, 217 ... 280, 299, 307 ... 370, 389, 398, 406 ... 460, 479 ... 497, 505 ... 550, 569 ... 596, 604 ... 640, 659 ... 695, 703 ... 730, 749 ... 794, 802 ... 820, 839 ... 893, 901, 910, 929 ... 992, 1009 ...

you see that the distance between adjacent round numbers is most often 9 (whenever I printed '...' above). However, there are bigger (e.g. between 280 and 299) and smaller gaps (e.g. between 794 and 802). A close inspection reveals that the number `N(k)` of round numbers less than `k` satisfies:

```
N(100)   = 9;
N(1000)  = 99;
N(10000) = 999; etc.
```

You may want to verify this and find a pattern for arbitrary large numbers. Then you can use that result to find the inverse, i.e. `k(N)`, which is your answer, in at most `log(N)` steps.